# HighCharts: Problems with creating custom tooltip, hiding 0 values from tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have facing three problems that I need to solve regarding HighCharts. If anyone knows the solution then please help. Here are the problems.

1. When I am trying to create a custom tooltip. The default custom tooltip box still appears. Along with the custom tooltip. Although the default tooltip is blank with no data in it, custom one shows all the data. But I'm not able to disable the default tooltip.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have multiple instances of `chart.tooltip` as well as assigning `tooltip` properties inside the series themselves. Set all global options in `chart.tooltip` and set series specific items (such as formatter) in the `series.tooltip` sections. These overlapping tooltip options/settings are causing all kinds of havoc on your chart.

Comment: @wergeld What about in the second chart. I'm not using multiple instances of the tooltip there just chart.tooltip just it behaves strangely when I set useHTML: true  the custom tooltip appears along with the default blank tooltip. What's the problem there. How can I disable the default tooltip and use the custom one instead. Can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: In the second one where you do `formatter: retrieveToolTip` you stomp on it again when you apply `headerformat`. The `tooltip.formatter` should be used OR the `tooltip.headerformat`. Can you set up a jsFiddle with a reproduceable example as I see no definition of your `retrieveToolTip`.